# Can't figure out how to deal with clang error due to duplicate symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've encountered this clang error:

duplicate symbol _downloading in:

```
/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SD-QuickPic-bloifhodgiduzhdygkblxycilunk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SD-QuickPic.build/Debug-iphoneos/SD-QuickPic.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DispatchList.o

/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SD-QuickPic-bloifhodgiduzhdygkblxycilunk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SD-QuickPic.build/Debug-iphoneos/SD-QuickPic.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DispatchImageList.o
```

ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've found similar issues to this and tried to implement their solutions to no avail.

The current work-around is to change all instances of "downloading" in this .h file to "downloadingImage". This has made the error go away but may not be the proper solution.

```
#import "DispatchImageList.h"
#import "Constants.h"
#import "FrapiTransaction.h"
#import "FrapiManager.h"

@implementation DispatchImageList

BOOL downloadingImage;

- (id) initWithDispatch:(Dispatch*)dispatch {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        downloadingImage = false;
        _dispatch = dispatch;
    }

    return self;
}

- (BOOL) isDownloading {
    return downloadingImage;
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you post the interface for those two files?

Comment: I'm new to a lot of this stuff, learned objective C and Xcode "trial by fire" style. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: If you're talking objective C, it's basically the .h file.  You've might have globally defined `downloading` in both those files.

Comment: #define CELL_DOWNLOADING_IMAGE_LIST @"cellDownloadingImageList" and #define CELL_DOWNLOADING_DISPATCHES @"cellDownloadingDispatches"

Comment: These are the only things defined in my constants.h that have anything to do with downloading as far as I can tell

Comment: Most likely both `DispatchList.m` and `DispatchImageList.m` directly or indirectly import a common .h file and that .h file declares something named `downloading`. Find the .h with that declaration and post it in your question.

Comment: rmaddy your answer fixed it! "downloading" was declared in both of those files. As soon as I changed the name of one declaration the build succeeded with no error.

Comment: @Alex Simply renaming is not really the proper solution. That just gets around the issue for now. You really should your question with the one or two .h files that have/had your `downloading` declaration. Then someone could help you do it correctly. BTW - be sure to put a `@` before a person's username.

Comment: Thank for the tip @rmaddy. I added the code of the .h file I changed. Changing all instances of "downloading" to "downloadingImage".

Comment: FYI - that was a .m, not a .h. But that's not important. See my answer for the proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a serious flaw in your .m file. Your `downloading` (`downloadingImage`) variable is a global variable, not an instance variable of the class.

Change these two lines:

```
@implementation DispatchImageList

BOOL downloadingImage;
```

to:

```
@implementation DispatchImageList {
    BOOL downloadingImage;
}
```

By putting the variable in the curly braces of the `@implementation` line, the variable changes from being a global to an instance variable. Now you won't have any name conflict and you can name the variable without any worry of some other class having the same instance variable name. And, more importantly, each instance of the class now gets its own copy of the variable instead of all instances in your app sharing the same global variable.

Comment: Thanks for including an explanation for why it works this way. Very helpful.